# How to write a utf8 string as binary

Tags: perl, utf-8, mojo

I have an epub that has been **double encoded** to utf8. I wanted to fix it by decoding it once and write it as binary but I get "wide character in subroutine" error. I'm using Mojo::File.

```
use Mojo::Base -strict;
use Mojo::File;
use Encode qw( decode_utf8 encode_utf8 );

my $in = Mojo::File->new('part0000.html')->slurp();
my $out = decode_utf8($in);
utf8::downgrade($out);
Mojo::File->new('string.html')->spurt($out);
```

I get the same error if I try this.

```
my $in = Mojo::File->new('part0000.html')->slurp();
my $out = encode_utf8(decode_utf8(decode_utf8($in)));
Mojo::File->new('string.htm')->spurt($out);
```

The decode seems to work but I can't figure out how to write it out as binary.
Any suggestions appreciated. [part0000.html](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nwuxtwl6k2ox84c/part0000.html?raw=1)

Comment: A utf8-encoded string is already represented as octets. You can write it without decoding.

Comment: [Both of your solutions work](https://gist.github.com/ikegami/6422f3bdd4e60af5b9c0cd45322aa20d) (although the downgrade is useless).

Comment: Re "*I get "wide character in subroutine" error.*", Then your file wasn't double-encoded as you claim.

Comment: FYI, In Python it's `open('part0000.html', encoding='utf8').read().encode('ansi').decode('utf8')`, where `ansi` is the system locale (`cp1252` on my system) but passes through undefined bytes (unlike `cp1252`).  Don't know perl well enough to answer.

Comment: Still waiting for a demonstration of the problem...

Comment: @Mark Tolonen, Re "*Don't know perl well enough to answer.*", As mentioned above, both of the snippets in the OP's question do what the OP asks. You can even remove the `utf8::downgrade($out);`. There's no separate byte strings and character strings in Perl, so it's a lot simpler.

Answer (score -1):

Apparently, it's impossible to simply write a utf8 string as binary in Perl  because of "wide character". I solved it a different way with regex.

Comment: Nonsense. That message means you are trying to write something that isn't a byte to a file, but files can only contain bytes.  *That* is impossible. But that's not "writing a utf8 string as binary". That is entirely possible.